# Looping through C struct w/o union

Tags: c, struct

My intention: To loop through -- without using unions -- 30 members of a structure, all of type character array, storing in each the result of a call to itoa. In the following code, I name the structure members a-z,A-D. In the calling function, I initialize a string of those characters, called 'letters', then I try to loop through the structure members by referring to them with my increment variable as the index into letters. Then, I try to dump the contents of each member of the structure. **edit: I realize that the members wouldn't contain anything, given what code you can see. The problem seems to be with referring to struct members like this.

```
struct listArrays {

    char a[10];
    char b[10];
    char c[10];
    char d[10];
    char e[10];
    char f[10];
    char g[10];
    char h[10];
    char i[10];
    char j[10];
    char k[10];
    char l[10];
    char m[10];
    char n[10];
    char o[10];
    char p[10];
    char q[10];
    char r[10];
    char s[10];
    char t[10];
    char u[10];
    char v[10];
    char w[10];
    char x[10];
    char y[10];
    char z[10];
    char A[10];
    char B[10];
    char C[10];
    char D[10];

};

struct listArrays Ternaries;

int testTernary(){

    char letters[30] = "ABCDabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 30; ++i){
        dumpArray((Ternaries.(letters[i])), 10);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The error I get is "expected identifier before '(' token."

Problems I have ruled out:

```
    -The dumpArray function works fine.
    -Looping through the letters works fine, outside the context of the 
     referral to struct members
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: you can't use a variable to reference a struct member like that.

Comment: That's far from being C. Why don't you use a 2D array for whatever you try?

Comment: Array's don't work that way. You need to use an associative container from `char` to `char[]` if you want to access by character or a 2D array, if you just want multiple arrays in one struct.

Comment: Paul, is my example excessive, incomplete, or unverifiable?

Comment: Aha, associative containers sound like my solution. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identifiers (names) only exist in the program text. Once compiled and linked, they no longer exist. So you can't "index" the struct for the letter. What you can do is:

```
struct listArrays {

    char letters[30][10];
};
```

Now you can access these "letters":

```
dumpArray((Ternaries.letters[i]), 10);
```